# How do I track my published platform events in Production?

Tags: platform-event, debugging

I know we can't query a platform event. But do we have any option to track the published platform events? I have implemented platform events and Mulesoft is subscriber. What if in Production, Mulesoft doesn't receive a published event and from Salesforce side we need to find out whether the event was published or not?

I see one option is to store platform event data (including replayId) in a custom object through trigger on platform event and delete that data on a periodical basis.

Is there any better solution than what I mentioned above?

Comment: if you call `Eventbus.publish` and don't get an exception, then it published

Comment: Thanks @cropredy for your response. Actually I'm already doing exception handling and storing the failures in another object. Actually, the requirement is more of having track of published event which isn't a usual use case. This requirement came up when 3rd party platform informed us about receiving multiple events for the same request. Since debug logs weren't setup at that time, so it became very difficult to find out whether we actually published multiple platform events for the same type of request or not. I'm just trying to find out if here is anything out of the box solution available.

Comment: No OOTB solution. I would have a PE subscriber that logged into a custom object all the events you publish.